# Making a header of a 1 column file using bash

Tags: bash, header

I have a lot of text files that look like this:

```
1130727
1156131
1478153
1500941
1759026
1793786
1804302
2027901
2104981
2105878
```

I need to put a header on each one of them consisting of three different things: A number, representing the total number of lines, another number representing the last number minus the first number all divided by 1000 and the letter L. So my new file should look like this:

```
10 975.2 L
1130727
1156131
1478153
1500941
1759026
1793786
1804302
2027901
2104981
2105878
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need try first. There are three different things in header, which one do you face problem, or all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is a very basic programming task. But anyway, I will give You a solution. Maybe You learn something from it and will be able to solve similar task on Your own.

AWK should help here: `awk 'NR==1{first=$1}{sum+=$1;}END{last=$1;print NR,(last-first)/1000,"L";}' yourfile`